# tmuxinator generated bash script ruined by ruby error message that should be on stderr?

Tags: ruby, bash, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmuxinator

So I'm trying to bring me up a tmuxinator (version 1.1) window and panes...and when I do nothing happens...so I run this instead:

```
leeand00@me-host:~$ tmuxinator debug pwrsh_n_bash
/var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/tmuxinator-1.1.1/lib/tmuxinator/project.rb:352: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
#!/bin/bash

# Clear rbenv variables before starting tmux
unset RBENV_VERSION
unset RBENV_DIR
...
```

and I notice that some ruby library deep, deep down is complaining about a directory being writable at the top of the script that is generated and that's why it won't run...I copied just the bash script into another terminal and it runs just fine.

I went to the file in question:

```
   def extract_tmux_config
      options_hash = {}

      options_string = `#{show_tmux_options}` # <- THIS BEING LINE 352 from whence the warning came...
      options_string.encode!("UTF-8", invalid: :replace)
      options_string.split("\n").map do |entry|
        key, value = entry.split("\s")
        options_hash[key] = value
        options_hash
      end

      options_hash
    end
```

So I figure maybe it doesn't like the permissions on my `~/.tmux.conf`, they are a little goofy (thanks MS, every file in my OneDrive is `-rw-rw-rw-` using this WSL thing).

I try changing it:

```
$ chmod o-w ~/.tmux.conf
$ chmod g-w ~/.tmux
```

Now it's permissions are `-rw-r--r--`

I run `tmuxinator debug pwrsh_n_bash` again, and I still get the same error message at the top that prevents it from running...

Maybe it's the ~/.tmuxinator folder I think...

`chmod -R o-w ./.tmuxinator/`
`chmod -R g-w ./.tmuxinator/`

re-ran `$ tmuxinator debug pwrsh_n_bash`, still get the error at the top.

I'm aware that I have some of these writable folders on my mounted c drive but I don't understand what that has to do with this warning showing up and preventing me from terminal bliss.

What library causes this issue and how can I shut up it's warning?  And shouldn't that stuff be piped out to `stderr` instead of it showing up in my `stdout` or the file that this gem is trying to execute after writing it?

Comment: Hello try adding appendWindowsPath=false to the interop section in /etc/wsl.conf.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Is Ruby searching my Windows `PATH` when it hits that line of code?  Why does it illicit a warning?  I don't think it'll be a problem to change that setting, I guess I can always add anything I need back into my Linux `PATH` manually.

Comment: Yes because of this error: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c. Make me think that it is complaining about the added windows path in Linux. With this setting, it won't to it anymore.